# What are good reasons to use a custom error in JavaScript instead of just a string?

Tags: javascript

Normally, when I want to write a custom exception, it is because I want to trigger, catch and handle a known condition in an elegant way. Are there any down sides to avoid all the ceremony of [a custom error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types) and simply do the following:

```
const ERROR_OOPS = "oops"

try {

    throw ERROR_OOPS;

} catch (error) {

    if (error === ERROR_OOPS) {
        // handle oops case
        return;
    }

    // handle other errors
}
```

Comment: Your question concerns multiple aspects of this. It's all part of error handling, admittedly, but it concerns how errors are communicated (`return` vs `throw`), type of objects errors are (`Error`, custom subclasses of `Error`, strings / non-`Error` objects) and possibly other aspects. Your question will invariably involve opinion answers. My opinion is that it doesn't matter much as long as you make your code readable. That said, I prefer to use exceptions and never *return* errors. You also seldom need to log errors, typically as part of catching them, otherwise they're logged automatically.

Comment: If you're just throwing a string as an error message then that's all you need but a custom error object lets you attach more information. It's also cleaner to do `switch (typeof error)` to handle multiple errors than having to use an if else chain to catch both the error objects and your own strings.

Comment: `typeof error` is not going to return them actual class of error, it will yield `"object"` no matter the class. You could do `switch(error.constructor)` but it has issues of its own. Also if you want to attach information, throwing an object defined with a literal (`{ ... }`) will do fine. Which is all why I said that it doesn't matter much as long as the code is understood by their peers.

Answer (score 0):

Two occasions where you might consider a custom error:

1. You need to attach meta information about the error. As @amn mentioned, you could just throw a literal object with the payload, but then it gets tricky to identify the error type in the catch block.
2. You have many places from where you throw the custom error and for debugging purposes you want to do a deep stack trace from where it was thrown.

Comment: If what you posted above isn't an answer to your question -- and I am not entirely sure if it is -- then I'd suggest you integrate the content in the question instead. As for what you said, well, an object literal doesn't make identifying error tricky at all, you can absolutely `switch` on error object properties. Whatever you `throw` is almost guaranteed to be an object. And stack trace is available for most JavaScript runtimes, at least with a running debugger.